# Apps Script Sheets to Google Calendar String Class Error

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to connect Google Sheets to Google Calendar using AppScript. The purpose is to automatically add events in bulk from a sheet. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7I5k.png) is a sample with mock data.

Here is the code:

```
function addCalEvent() {

  let calenDar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('MyPRIVATECalendarID'); // get Calendar by ID
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Task_Pool'); // get spreadsheet
  let schedule = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  schedule.splice(0, 2); // cut the 2 top rows of data

  // a loop that should push every row of data to the selected calendar
  schedule.forEach(function (element) {
    calenDar.createEvent(element[0], element[6], element[7], 
    {description: element[4]},
    {location: element[5]}
    );
  });
};
```

When the function is run - it returns an error:

```
10:19:47 PM Notice  Execution started
10:19:49 PM Error   
Exception: The parameters (String,(class),(class),(class),(class)) don't match the method signature for CalendarApp.Calendar.createEvent.
(anonymous) @ Code.gs:11
addCalEvent @ Code.gs:10
```

I was expecting the events to push to the calendar without an error. I tried adding .toString() to element[6], element[7] of the loop. I've tried converting element[4] and element[5] to strings adding .toString() to them and then enclosing them inside () making a "new Date object". Didn't work.

I'm trying to repeat a YouTube [tutorial](https://youtu.be/kYmdsOvUOng?t=635), but for some reason I get the error. Sometimes the code passes through, if I remove description and location parameters. But these are vital to my use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this answer, it supposes that your columns "G" and "H" are the date object. Please be careful about this.

The arguments of `createEvent` are `title, startTime, endTime, options`. In your script, I think that the 5th argument of `{location: element[5]}` is not correct. I think that this might be the reason for your current issue. In order to avoid this issue, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function addCalEvent() {
  let calenDar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('MyPRIVATECalendarID');
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Task_Pool');
  let schedule = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  schedule.splice(0, 2);
  schedule.forEach(function (element) {
    calenDar.createEvent(
      element[0],
      element[6],
      element[7],
      { description: element[4], location: element[5] } // Modified
    );
  });
}
```

- When the values of columns "G" and "H" are the date object, an event is created by running this modified script.

#### Note:

- If the values of columns "G" and "H" are not the date object, please convert it to the date object, and test it again.

#### Reference:

- [createEvent(title, startTime, endTime, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#createEvent(String,Date,Date,Object))

Comment: Thank you very much, your suggestion to merge the additional options inside one pair of curly brackets seemed to have solved my problem!

Just one thing: the events are sent to the calendar, but I still see the same error: 

"Exception: The parameters (String,String,String,(class)) don't match the method signature for CalendarApp.Calendar.createEvent."

and about columns "G" and "H" being date object - I don't understand. My sheet reads the strings inside both columns as dates AND I've set up conditional formating to only allow dates in these columns. Is that good enough?

Comment: @Set Thank you for replying. From `Thank you very much, your suggestion to merge the additional options inside one pair of curly brackets seemed to have solved my problem!`, I understood that your issue was resolved.

Comment: @Set About your new issue of `Just one thing: the events are sent to the calendar, but I still see the same error: "Exception: The parameters (String,String,String,(class)) don't match the method signature for CalendarApp.Calendar.createEvent." and about columns "G" and "H" being date object - I don't understand. My sheet reads the strings inside both columns as dates AND I've set up conditional formating to only allow dates in these columns. Is that good enough?`, I would like to support you.

Comment: @Set But, I think that your previous error is `The parameters (String,(class),(class),(class),(class)) don't match the method signature for CalendarApp.Calendar.createEvent.`. And your new error is `The parameters (String,String,String,(class)) don't match the method signature for CalendarApp.Calendar.createEvent.`. I think that your new error is different from your initial error.

Comment: @Set I think that from `The parameters (String,(class),(class),(class),(class)) don't match the method signature for CalendarApp.Calendar.createEvent.`, unfortunately, `element[6]` and `element[7]` are not date objects. Please confirm it again.

Comment: @Set About `My sheet reads the strings inside both columns as dates AND I've set up conditional formating to only allow dates in these columns. Is that good enough?`, in order to confirm it, can you provide your sample Spreadsheet?

Comment: @Set By the way, about `and about columns "G" and "H" being date object - I don't understand.`, you can see about the date object at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: Thank you for your help! Sorry for responding late. I studied and solved the error. As you said - I only needed to make "new Date objects" from element[6] and element[7]. I did it. Everything wokrs just fine.

Thank you for the link to MDN, it was of most help!

Comment: I also found useful this interactive textbook: https://javascript.info/date. It helped me with further actions with Date objects and it's writen in simplier terms which is great for a beginner like myself. Maybe somebody reading this will also find it helpful